# How to build a sum of x on distinct y?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following setup:

Parent table:

| idParent | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |

Child table:

| idChild | idParent | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

I need to join those tables on `idParent` and group on `type`.

I have the following query

```
select c.type, sum(p.val) 
from parent as p 
join child as c on p.idParent = c.idParent
group by c.type
```

which gives me this result

| type | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 |
| 2 | 12 |

The `sum` on the first row is undesired as I would like to have a sum of `val` BUT only on unique `idParent`.

Expected output:

| type | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 |

So that the group of `type = 1` will check, if `val` of the same `idParent` was already included in the sum or not.

Is this possible?

Here a dbFiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/Y74_c1gP

https://dbfiddle.uk/VIXxf4sv (more data, and other combinations of child/type relation)

Expected output (with more data):

| type | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 114 |
| 2 | 125 |

Not sure if it is helpful in anyway this is how I would solve the issue in C#.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zbzbil

Note:

If possible I would like to keep the "structure" of the SQL untouched e.g. no CTE, no derived table, so only a change on the field.

I tried to use window functions, but this seems to be impossible with a `group by`.

Given the example provided by @Littlefoot, if the `val` field would be identical for different parents.

Note: the data is from the dbfiddle with more data, decided to show it here as to not have everything on external links

Parent table:

| idParent | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 (changed from 23 to 12, to reflect @Littlefoot's example) |
| 3 | 34 |
| 4 | 45 |
| 5 | 56 |

Child table:

| idChild | idParent | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 |

Expected result would be:

| type | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 103 |
| 2 | 114 |

Why?

Because

- `type 1` has the parents with `idParent` `1, 2, 3, 4` and I want to get a `sum` of those parents `val` field (only ONCE for each parent), which is `12 + 12 + 34 + 45 == 103`
- `type 2` has the parents with `idParent` `1, 2, 3, 5` and I want to get a `sum` of those parents `val` field (only ONCE for each parent), which is `12 + 12 + 34 + 56 == 114`

So to re-iterate I want to sum the field `val` only ONCE for each `idParent`, so even if there are 10 children with `idParent = 1` and `type = 1` it should only build the sum of the "first occurrence".

Comment: Could you add the expected output for your two dbFiddle examples? I'm not sure I understood the goal correctly.

Comment: @Ada - edited the question

Comment: Thanks! In that case my answer below seems to be correct.

Comment: @Ada - indeed it does, sadly I hoped it would be avoidable to "re-structure" the SQL and hoped there would be any in-built function supporting the desired output eg. `SUMBY(p.Val, p.idParent)` which sums first argument if second argument is unique.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know of any inbuilt function like that. How do you feel about stored procedures or user-defined functions?

Comment: @Ada - maybe I missed the news, but I thought aggregate functions can't be declared by user, or? but if that is possible, I would be more than happy about it

Comment: Apparently you're right, I couldn't get it to work :-/

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - 4.x

Comment: OK, the approach I was thinking of doesn't apply here. I think the current answers (and variants on it) are your only option.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - now you have me curious, could you maybe provide documentation or even give an answer how it would be possible on firebird 5.x? (assuming you mean it applies to 5.x) | we definitely plan to switch fast to firebird 5.x want to get the parallel processing of indexes, but not before final release.

Comment: @RandRandom I was thinking of an approach using a lateral join (introduced in Firebird 4.0), but that doesn't apply to your case, or at least, it isn't any simpler than the solutions in the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a subquery should work (if I understood the goal correctly):

```sql
SELECT c.type, SUM(p.val) AS sum_val
FROM parent AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT idParent, type
    FROM child
) AS c ON p.idParent = c.idParent
GROUP BY c.type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you literally do what you described (or, should I say *what I understood*,  `SUM(DISTINCT val)` ):

```
SQL> select c.type, sum(distinct p.val) as result
  2  from parent  p
  3  join child  c on p.idParent = c.idParent
  4  group by c.type
  5  order by c.type;
```

you'd get desired result:

```
      TYPE             RESULT
---------- ------------------
         1                114
         2                125
```

---

However, what result do you expect if sample data was

```
insert into parent values(1, 12);        --> same value for ID = 1
insert into parent values(2, 12);        --> and ID = 2
```

(the rest is as you put it).

My query returns

```
      TYPE             RESULT
---------- ------------------
         1                 91
         2                102
```

Is that OK?

---

**[EDIT]** No, that wasn't OK. With new sample data and desired result, here's a new query:

```
SQL> select type, sum(val) total
  2  from (select distinct c.idparent, c.type, p.val
  3        from child c join parent p on p.idparent = c.idparent
  4       )
  5  group by type;

      TYPE      TOTAL
---------- ----------
         1        103
         2        114
```

I hope that's better; it also returns 114/125 for the "old" data set.

Comment: No, that is not okay. The `12` should be used twice because it’s a `val` from a different `idParent`.

Comment: I thought so. Which result do you expect in that case?

Comment: edited the question to show the expected result

Comment: OK, thank you. I edited answer and posted new query. Have a look, please.